# How to find differences between 2 tables with different key names

Tags: sql

So say I have 2 tables. TableA has keys FirstName, LastName, Age, Location. TableB has keys 1FirstName, 1LastName, 1Age, 1Location. Table A is a working table, and TableB is a reference table. How could I go about finding what records exist in TableB that DO NOT exist in TableA

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: EXCEPT, MINUS depending on your DBMS

Answer (score 1):

Using an outer join will join all rows of left table to either right table or NULL
Then including only NULL from right hand side will give you what you need.
TableB as left side

```
SELECT
 *
FROM (
SELECT
  b.*,
  a.*
FROM TableB b
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA a
ON
  b.1FirstName = a.Firstname
  AND
  b.1LastName = a.Lastname
  AND
  b.1Age = a.Age
  AND
  b.1Location = a.Location
) q
WHERE q.FirstName IS NULL
```